# Modified Redmine port, but the links of email notifications are still default

Tags: port, redmine, email-notifications

I start redmine like this:

```
ruby /usr/share/redmine/script/server webrick -e production -b m.y.i.p -p 90 -d
```

and it runs well. Then I create an issue, and the **email notifications** will send the issue's link to my email which contains the html link tag like:  `<a href="http://m.y.i.p:3000/issues/16#change-19">16#</a>`

Pay attention to the attribute **href** of the link tag, the port is still the default **3000**! It means it links to an invalid address when I click it.

**The correct link would be:**

```
<a href="http://m.y.i.p:90/issues/16#change-19">16#</a>
```

It must be something I forget to config. What am I supposed to do? I really don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I was solving a similar problem and found the following steps recommended in [the project forum](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/2436):

1. Click on Adminstration in the topmost bar.
2. Click on Settings on the new page.
3. Click on the general tab.
4. About two-thirds down the page is a text box labeled host name.